# How to select highest valued row by group in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset of genes in groups called 'loci' I am looking to select the gene with the higest score compared against only the genes in the same loci/group

My input data looks like this:

```
    loci Gene     Score
1:    1  AQP11   0.5566507
2:    1 CLNS1A   0.2811747
3:    1   RSF1   0.5269924
4:    2  CFDP1   0.4186066
5:    2  CHST6   0.5395135
```

My output would select the gene for group/loci 1 that has the highest score out of the 3 genes in loci 1, then also the gene with the highest score when compared with only the other gene in group 2.

So the output from this example I'm trying to get is:

```
     loci  Gene     Score
1:    1    AQP11   0.5566507 #highest score in loci 1
2:    2    CHST6   0.5395135 #highest score in loci 2
```

How can I filter for highest score by row groupings? I'm not sure where to start with this.

Input data:

```
structure(list(loci = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Gene = c("AQP11", 
"CLNS1A", "RSF1", "CFDP1", "CHST6"), Score = c(0.556650698184967, 
0.281174659729004, 0.526992380619049, 0.418606609106064, 0.539513528347015
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

I've been trying something with dplyr with `dplyr::group_by()` but I keep getting various errors.

Comment: If there is a tie, do you want all genes, or randomly pick one?

Comment: Very good point, I hadn't considered, it shouldn't happen, but if it does I would want all genes

Comment: This question has surely been answered b4 on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(loci) %>% filter(Score == max(Score))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   loci [2]
   loci Gene  Score
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 AQP11 0.557
2     2 CHST6 0.540
```

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .SD[which.max(Score)], by = loci]

   loci  Gene     Score
1:    1 AQP11 0.5566507
2:    2 CHST6 0.5395135
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `subset`

```
subset(dt,ave(Score,loci,FUN = max)==Score)
```

giving

```
   loci  Gene     Score
1:    1 AQP11 0.5566507
2:    2 CHST6 0.5395135
```

---

Another base R option using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~loci,dt[with(dt,order(-Score,loci)),],head,1)
```

giving

```
  loci  Gene             Score
1    1 AQP11 0.556650698184967
2    2 CHST6 0.539513528347015
```